# Accessing external website returns IIS generic page

Tags: windows, web, iis-7

I'm not attempting any hosting on my local machine. All I'm trying to do is access to http://www.pluralsight.com/ and I get the following response.

[image]

I'm able to access this website on other PCs, but it just fails  on a particular one. I've tried stopping my IIS service, refresh IP address, flush DNS Cache but none of them works.

Comment: What DNS servers are you using? Do you have any records for that domain in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Along the same lines, what do you see if you run 'nslookup www.pluralsight.com' on the affected machine? (Or dig if you're on a *nix).

Comment: Its indeed the DNS settings. I reconfigured and now I'm able to access the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your DNS server to Google Public DNS IP Address.
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en

Comment: to downvoter : do you want to explain why you put the downvote ?